# How many rectangles of different sizes are there on the standard chessboard that have equal area black and white?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, chessboard

I know that the number of rectangles on a standard chessboard are ${9 \choose 2}\cdot {9  \choose 2}$. How to compute the ones having equal areas of black and white?

Comment: Possible ambiguity: do the sides of the rectangle have to be parallel with the sides of the board?

Comment: Assuming that the sides of the rectangle have to be parallel with the sides of the board, and that the 4 corners of the rectangle have to be *grid points*, the only way to have the rectangle violate the constraint of equal black-white area is if there are an odd number of rows and an odd number of columns.

Comment: So what do you know about rectangles that do not have the same amount of white and black? What dimensions can they have? Knowing that, how many are there? Subtract that from the total number of rectangles.

Comment: Of course, you mean the rectangle formed by rows and columns. Any rectangle with equal area of black and white has even width or height (in colums or row), you can just exclude all rectangles with odd width and height, whose number is equal to number of rectangles in chessboard $4\times 4$.

Comment: @user2661923 yes, they have to be parallel. Sorry for missing out on that detail. Apologies.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you for so much help. Yes, now I see that the rectangles which violate the said constraint are really the ones with odd width, and height. But how did you come up with the fact that their number will be equal to the aforementioned thing stated by you? Can you please help as how to determine number of rectangles with odd width and height if I didn't know the fact that their number will be same as the ones on 4 x 4 board.

Comment: The odd-sized rectangles on an 8x8 board won't be the same in number as the number of rectangles on a 4x4. Label the vertical edge lines of the squares of the board from 1 to 9. To choose the two vertical sides of your odd-sized rectangle, you need to choose 2 of the 9 vertical lines similar to before, but now they need to be an odd distance apart. So one of them has an even label, the other an odd label. So instead of $\binom{9}{2}$ you simply have $4\cdot5$ because there are 4 even and 5 odd labels. Same for the horizontal lines.